# Convert excel 1 column to multiple csv column

Tags: excel, csv

I have question

There are excel data like this
[input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5egQf.png)

More than 500 person
I wanna convert data to csv
[expected csv result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thl1I.png)

The data age is not 100% the second row, some may be third row. Name can be duplicate data.

I’m really confused. Can i use excel feature to do this or any way like coding?

I upload file : https://ufile.io/rxe1l

Comment: Please attach a sample file

Comment: I think there is no attach file feature on mobile app.

Comment: Please attach a sample file, using a PC

Answer (score 0):

Add name, age, add etc as column in excel and export as .csv.

1. In your Excel workbook, switch to the File tab, and then click Save As. Alternatively, you can press F12 to open the same Save As dialog.

[image]

2. In the Save as type box, choose to save your Excel file as CSV (Comma delimited).

[image]

Please simply follow this link [conversation excel into csv](https://youtu.be/RW0BTP-XyeY)

Comment: Thankyou for convert csv guide. Btw, the hard part is I have to copy each of row. To each multiple column. Because all excel data are only in 1 column. It’s like transpose feature of excel. But I have to continue loop transpose 3 rows to be 3 fields csv until the end of 500 sets of data.